# Server Essentials 2012 No Devices Page

Tags: windows-server-2012, dashboard

Server 2012 Essentials - The dashboard does not show the Devices page. I found a similar post where a guy deleted the DevicesInfo.xml and replaced with the .bak file - but that has not worked for me.

Restarts do not make the page appear.

Does anyone have any ideas? The computers (except 1 XP box) have been connected with the connector software.

[image]

Comment: Try to open Dashboard -> Help -> Safe mode settings, then select the "Devices" add-in, click the Enable button and restart Dashboard.

Comment: Please make your comment into an answer so I can award you the bounty. Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this procedure :

1. Open `Dashboard` -> `Help` -> `Safe mode settings`
2. Select the `Devices` add-in
3. Click the `Enable` button
4. Restart Dashboard.